# How to calculate volatility with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate the volatiity with python pandas. As indicated by http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0180-enhancements the syntax might have changed.

Unfortunately, both (old and new) syntax do not work.

What did I get wrong?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3,4, 5, 6]})
print("pd.__version__:", pd.__version__)
# pd.__version__: 0.23.4
df['vola'] = pd.rolling_std(df['a'], window=2)
# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_std'
df['vola'] = df['a'].rolling_std(window=2)
#AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rolling_std'
```

Comment: Try `df['a'].rolling(window=2).std()`

Comment: You're using the deprecated version of that function. `pd.rolling_mean is deprecated for DataFrame and will be removed in a future version, replace with
                       DataFrame.rolling(window=3, center=False).mean()`. Though that's for mean, it's the same for `.std`

Comment: Be extra careful if this is a financial time-series - in that case, you'd want to take the log or some rate-of-change (ROC) on prices before doing the std(), or you will get bad results (eg equity prices drift upward so without taking log or ROC, you will have non-stationarity).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandas doesn't have a `rolling-std`, so use `rolling` and get `std` with he function `std` of `rolling` like the below:

```
df['vola'] = df['a'].rolling(window=2).std()
```

Then you will get the right result.

Comment: Hi @U12-Forward - why did you choose not to use the standard deviation with `ddof=0`?

Comment: If you have complete historical data, you are not trying to estimate an unknown volatility and therefore you should divide std dev with N-0. If you only have a small sample and try to estimate volatility, you should divide std dev with N-1 like usual. Because you want to calculate a window of 2, you have complete data, and therefore you should divide std dev with N-0, that is, you should use "...window=2).std(ddof=0)". If you want to divide with "N-1", then "std()" is correct.